# Problemas com charset no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebird, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho um banco de dados `Firebird` que não foi construído através de `migrations` no [Laravel](https://www.laravel.com), e ele possui codificação `ISO-8859-1` e preciso retornar um objeto no formato `JSON` para minha aplicação, porém, ao fazer isso, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> "The Response content must be a string of object implementing ___toString(), "boolean" given."

Este erro acontece, porque **objetos** `JSON` precisam ser construídos a partir de strings `UFT-8`. Porém, considero desnecessário ter que a todo momento ter que fazer esse tipo de conversão, além da minha aplicação perder desempenho devido a isso.

Estou utilizando diversos **Models** do `Laravel`, porém, há algum método específico em que consigo fazer esse tipo de conversão sem ter que criar `loop` e **converter** manualmente?

Comment: coloque todo código relacionado ao erro, e o problema? porque tem erros e problemas no seu questionamento? `model`, `tabela e seu layout` são bem vindos, eu até imagino a solução, mas, eu preciso visualizar aonde colocar !

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar a técnica de [*Accessors & Mutators*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), onde a formatação do campo é feita direto `model`:

Vou propor *um exemplo*, porque, na sua pergunta não tem um `model` e seria importante ter e o ***layout da tabela*** por causa dos campos, mas, vou generalizar com um exemplo básico.

***Exemplo:***

No seu caso em especifico o fator exibição é o que precisa:

```
<?php

namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Noticias extends Model
{    
    public function getTituloAttribute($value)
    {
        return strtoupper($value);
    }
}
```

Dentro da tabela ***`noticias`***, tem um campo com o nome **titulo**, preciso que na exibição fica todo em maiúsculo, então cria um método de mutação ***`get`*** que automaticamente faz a conversão especifica do campo **titulo**.

***Normas:***

> `get` + nome do campo + `Attribute($value)`

se o campo for *separado* por `underscore` como exemplo `primeiro_nome` ficaria:

```
public function getPrimeiroNomeAttribute($value)
```

ou seja, as iniciais em maiúsculo entre `underscore`

---

Tem também o `set` que seria uma modificação de alteração do valor enviado, colocando também efeitos e mudanças significativas no valor desse campo, refletindo toda essa alteração na sua tabela.

***Normas:***

> `set` + nome do campo + `Attribute($value)`

Código com o mesmo campo `titulo` da tabela `noticias` (*fictício exemplo*):

```
public function setTituloAttribute($value)
{
     $this->attributes['titulo'] = $value;
}
```

---

Código completo *fictício* exemplo `Model Noticias`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Noticias extends Model
{    
    // GET
    public function getTituloAttribute($value)
    {
        return strtoupper($value);
    }
    // SET
    public function setTituloAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['titulo'] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso resolvi no database config do Laravel, definindo a collation = iso e charset = utf8

```
    'oracle' => [
        'driver' => 'oracle',            
        'host' => 'seu host',
        'port' => 'porta',
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'senha',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'WE8ISO8859P1',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```